# How to avoid saving other records in a custom VF page

Tags: controller, custom-controller

I created a custom list of Event records using a custom controller and Visualforce page. In the list, the user can edit an Event but after saving the change, it also changes the last modified date of the other records on the list, even though there was no change to the data of those other records. What can I do so that Salesforce will only update the record that was changed?
Below is my current custom controller:

```
public class EventsMDHomePage{

    public List<Event> eventsToday {get; set;}

    public EventsMDHomePage() {
        eventsToday = [
            SELECT FIELDS(STANDARD)
            FROM Event
            WHERE OwnerId =: UserInfo.getUserId() AND ActivityDate =: date.today()
            ORDER BY StartDateTime ASC
            LIMIT 1000];
    }
    
    public PageReference saveEvents() {
        try{
            update eventsToday;
        }
        catch(DmlException ex){
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
        }
        return null;
    }      
}
```

Comment: Your question is an example of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Yes, the update will modify the timestamp but it will only change field values that are different on original vs new record. Please edit your question and clarify your goals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need an original copy of the list to compare to:

```
public class EventsMDHomePage{
    public List<Event> eventsToday {get; set;}
    List<Event> originalEvents;
    public EventsMDHomePage() {
        eventsToday = [
            SELECT FIELDS(STANDARD)
            FROM Event
            WHERE OwnerId =: UserInfo.getUserId() AND ActivityDate =: date.today()
            ORDER BY StartDateTime ASC
            LIMIT 1000];
        originalEvents = eventsToday.deepClone(true, true, true);
    }
    
    public void saveEvents() {
        List<Event> recordsToSave = new List<Event>();
        for(Integer i = 0, s = eventsToday.size(); i < s; i++) {
            if(originalEvents[i] != eventsToday[i]) {
                recordsToSave.add(eventsToday[i])
            }
        }
        try{
            update recordsToSave;
        }
        catch(DmlException ex){
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
        }
    }      
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help! I tried it and it worked. I'm just wondering, do you know if this is a best practice for cases of inline editing in record collections or does it have any negative impact on performance? On my end I didn't notice any significant performance issue.